# jQuery "'events' is null or not an object" error, when using empty() or html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, dhtml

I am getting the following error in IE:

> 'events' is null or not an object -- jquery-latest.js?d=1848173663, line 113 character 467

I am using jQuery 1.4.2, I'm not in a position to upgrade yet as we are on an older version of jQuery UI and have way too many bugs using anything newer than 1.4.2.

I get following error when I run this bit of code the **second time**:

```
$.post("page/view.do?undoCache=" + Math.random(), {
   pageId: pId
}, function(xmlContent){
   console.log('1');//get this one
   $('#reloadCenterDiv').empty();
   console.log('2');//don't get this one unless line above is commented out, then will run til next line
   $('#reloadCenterDiv').html(xmlContent);
   console.log('3');//don't get this
});
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything else to #reloadCenterDiv between calls.

Googling around for the error "'events' is null or not an object" I found this:

> "Sounds like a reference to an event
>   handler is still there, when the
>   handler itself is already gone."

That sounds logical. Any other ideas of why and when this error would occur?

I have found where this is happening, but all clues for me end there.

How do I clean things up so I can call empty() or html() on #reloadCenterDiv again?

Here is the HTML for #reloadCenterDiv:

```
<div id="reloadCenterDiv" style="border:none; margin: 0; overflow:auto; overflow-y:scroll; height: auto;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but it would seem like `jQuery.cache` is being overwritten.

Since a DOM element has (when necessary) a serial number that maps to `jQuery.cache`, when you run a function like `.empty()`, jQuery assumes the related data exists, looks up the data for that element, and deletes it.

In place of your first log, do this:

```
console.log(jQuery.cache);
```

And see what it gives you. I'll bet that something is overwriting it. Perhaps you're loading jQuery twice?

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/4N8WH/) that intentionally deletes `jQuery.cache`. It gives a similar error.

---

**EDIT:**

Summary of the comments below. During `.empty()` (or actually `cleanData()`) jQuery grabs the expando from all descendant elements in order to delete the associated data.

The issue is that when jQuery does so, it *assumes* that the data was successfully located. In this case, somehow the data is being disassociated from the element, so retrieving the data using the value of the expando is returning `undefined`.

Because jQuery doesn't (or didn't in 1.4.2) verify that data was found, its attempt to access the `events` property on the data is causing an error, because again `data` is `undefined`.

Updated versions of jQuery fix it with `if ( data && data.events ) {`, which verifies that there is some object against which to ask for its `events` property.

Comment: 1st and 2nd calls both return [object Object] in IE developer tools. How do I see what the object is? Will checking this out in Firebug do any good? I don't get the error in FireFox.

Comment: @Dale - Yes, Firebug or Google Chrome's tools should let you example the content of the object. Sounds like you have an object there. Try doing `console.log(jQuery.cache[1])`. Is there any chance that another version of jQuery is being loaded somewhere? Perhaps via an AJAX call? I believe this could overwrite the cache with a new version.

Comment: @patrick dw - No, there is only one instance of jQuery loaded. Just checked now to make extra sure.

Comment: @patrick dw - console.log(jQuery.cache[1]); still just return [object Object]

Comment: @Dale - I assume you're not using a CDN? Just asking because the error in your code states `jquery-latest.js`.

Comment: @patrick dw - Correct, I'm not using a CDN. Just the way I name my files so I can update versions without changing the file name.

Comment: Obviously it works the first time, but the object created for #reloadCenterDiv loses 'events' somewhere down the line. It would be ideal to find what is causing that, i.e. find out what would likely cause it to happen, and look for that. However, for the sake of testing, is there a way to reestablish the object so 'events' is no longer null? Basically, force jQuery to recreate the object?

Comment: @Dale - Not much I can do without seeing more. Take a look [here at the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/manipulation.js#L555-560) for jQuery 1.4.2. You'll see that it looks for the expando property, then retrieves the `data` for that element `data = cache[ id ];`. It assumes it was successful because the next line is `if ( data.events ) {...`. So if it was in fact not successful in getting the data, it would be trying to get the `events` property of `undefined`. This is likely the cause of the error.

Comment: @Dale - When you do `.empty()` it iterates through *all* the descendant elements of `reloadCenterDiv`. As such, the error could be on *any* descendant that received any sort of data from jQuery.

Comment: @patrick dw - Gee, there's a lot of content. I get this when I don't call .empty() as well. Happens with .html() also. Any ideas about my question in the comment above about recreating the object?

Comment: @Dale - `.html()` does the same thing. Tries to clean up the data so you don't have memory leaks. I'm not certain that jQuery's method of managing handlers is a good system. With regard to recreating the object, say if one of those elements has the serial number `123`. Then somehow `jQuery.cache` is overwritten with a new copy, so now the space at `123` happens to be `undefined`. You could try doing `jQuery.cache[123] = {}`. Then in the code I pointed out, jQuery would be able to test `data.events` and see that there's no property. Trouble is that you don't know the serial numbers. ...more...

Comment: ...Another possibility would be to try to get the name of the expando property jQuery is setting on the elements. It's always something like `jQuery1291414164391`. Basically "jQuery" plus a timestamp. Then you could go through all the elements yourself, and remove the expando so jQuery doesn't try to clean up the data. This is not a solution though. Somehow the previous data is being overwritten (I'm pretty certain), so you'll need to find out how/why. Any chance this site is publicly available?

Comment: @patrick dw - This bug is not on the public site, haven't committed yet because of the bug. I might have it up later today or after the weekend. I will let you know.

Comment: @Dale - Ok, let me know. Also, I understand that you can't upgrade, but it may be worth trying with 1.4.4 just out of curiosity to see if it was a bug that's been fixed. I know there have been bugs in the past with regard to overwriting data. If it is fixed, then we may be able to track down the issue in jQuery's bugtracker and see if there's a workaround.

Comment: @patrick dw - Very good thinking. 1.4.4 does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: @patrick dw - K, got it fixed. I noticed that they simply checked for data && data.events. So I modified 1.4.2 and it works now. How should I go about accepting an answer? Could you summarize what you led me to find with the solution so I can give you credit?

Comment: @Dale, sure I'll update in a minute. Glad you got it working. :o)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't update your jQuery, you can set the HTML instead:

```
$("#divid").html("");
```

This is essentially doing the same thing.